# AccessController checkPermission always throws exception

Tags: java

How do you check if the application has permission to read or write to specific directories on the filesystem. I am trying this:

```
try {
    AccessController.checkPermission(new FilePermission(files[i]
            .getAbsolutePath(), "read,write"));
}
catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println(e.toString());
}
```

but it always throws the exception and outputs:

```
java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.io.FilePermission" "C:\Dell" "read")
java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.io.FilePermission" "C:\Documents and Settings" "read")
java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.io.FilePermission" "C:\glut-3.7.6" "read")
```

Is there something I'm missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that `AccessController` always throws an exception when you don't have permission. You can handle this by catching `SecurityException`.

Better solution to check read/write permission with `java.io.File.canRead()`, `java.io.File.canWrite()` methods.

Comment: I've tried the java.io.File.canRead() but that returns true for every directory.

Comment: Actually, I think this might work if I check canRead on a file within the directory.

Answer (score 0):

Text from documentation :

> ```
>  Determines whether the access request indicated by the
>  specified permission should be allowed or denied, based on
>  the security policy currently in effect, and the context in
>  this object. The request is allowed only if every ProtectionDomain
>  in the context implies the permission. Otherwise the request is
>  denied.
> ```