# Struts 2 Download File is 0 bytes

Tags: java, file, jsp, struts2

I'm having an issue downloading a file using Struts2. I've done a pile of research and found a bunch of similar questions, but none of the answers have helped me out.

Here is what I currently have

**JSP**

```
<s:url id="fileDownload" namespace="/jsp" action="download"></s:url>
Download file - <s:a href="%{fileDownload}">MyFile.pdf</s:a>
```

**Action**

```
private InputStream inputStream;
private String fileName;
public String execute() throws Exception {
        File fileToDownload = new File("C:My Documents/MyFile.pdf");
        fileName = fileToDownload.getName();
        inputStream = new FileInputStream(fileToDownload);      
        return SUCCESS;
    }

public String getFileName() {
    return fileName;
}

public void setFileName(String fileName) {
    this.fileName = fileName;
}

public InputStream getInputStream() {
    return inputStream;
}
```

**Struts.xml**

```
<action name="download" class="com.my.path.to.action.class">
        <result name="success" type="stream">
                <param name="contentDisposition">attachment;filename=${fileName}</param>
                <param name="contentType">application/pdf</param>
                <param name="inputName">inputStream</param>
                <param name="bufferSize">4096</param>
        </result>
</action>
```

When I click on the link, it will download a file that's named correctly, but it has no data in it. If anyone has any ideas as to what I'm doing wrong, I would love a suggestion as I'm sure it's just something dumb.

Comment: `new File("C:My Documents/MyFile.pdf")` - a slash is missing after `C:`

Comment: The slash isn't required. I added it anyway, and the result is the same.

Comment: What does `fileToDownload.exists()` return?

Comment: [make sure the file is readable](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11902032/573032)

Comment: It returns true for both existing and being readable.

Comment: I've also checked the length and it displays the proper length.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found my answer. You must define the content length in struts. To do this I did the following:

**Struts.xml**

```
<param name="contentLength">${contentLength}</param>
```

**Action**

```
private long contentLength;
public long getContentLength() {
    return contentLength;
}

public void setContentLength(long contentLength) {
    this.contentLength = contentLength;
}
```

*in execute()*

```
contentLength = fileToDownload.length();
```